# Redirecting into Subfolder and masking this with Apache Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i got a subfolder inside my domains root directory, lets call it "domain.tld/subfolder". Inside this "subfolder" there are more subfolders, one of them is called "public". Now when I request "domain.tld/subfolder" i want the user to see the content of "subfolder/public", but without changing the URL to "domain.tld/subfolder/public".

Any Ideas on this??

Answer (score 0):

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Use `.htaccess` to redirect.